# Unable to print the updated values for a modified object in python

Tags: python, loops, struct, scope

I am trying to modify a field in a structure object. Basically, I am trying to set the values from [True, True, True] to [False,False,False] for certain atoms.These appear as T T T next to the atoms in the file. This is what I tried:

```
import pymatgen.io.vaspio as iopy
import numpy as np
import json

np.zdiff=[]  # to store the z coordinates of atoms

struc = iopy.Poscar.from_file("POSCAR") # read the structure file

for i in range(len(struc.structure)):
        np.zdiff.append(struc.structure[i].z) 

unique=set(np.zdiff)
newzdiff=list(unique)
zval=sorted(newzdiff)  # z coordinated sorted

for i in xrange(len(struc.structure)):
        if struc.structure[i].z <= float(zval[1]): # if z is <= a value
                #np.reg1.append(struc[i].z)
                struc.structure[i].selective_dynamics=[True,True,True]

        elif struc.structure[i].z <= float(zval[3]): # second condition
                #np.reg2.append(struc[i].z)
                struc.structure[i].selective_dynamics=[False,False,False]
        struc.write_file("POSCAR.2") # write the file here
```

The [True True True] values remain the same in POSCAR.2. However, when I run the above code interactively:

struc.structure[21].selective_dynamics gives [False, False, False] while it was [True, True, True] initially

In other words, it has been modified according to the program. why does it not print it in the file?

This is the original file that I am reading:

```
  0.0000000000000000  0.2500000000000000  0.2500000000000000  T T T
  0.2500000000000000  0.0000000000000000  0.2500000000000000  T T T
  0.2500000000000000  0.2500000000000000  0.0000000000000000  T T T
  0.5000000000000000  0.2500000000000000  0.2500000000000000  T T T
  0.7500000000000000  0.0000000000000000  0.2500000000000000  T T T
  0.7500000000000000  0.2500000000000000  0.0000000000000000  T T T
  0.0000000000000000  0.7500000000000000  0.2500000000000000  T T T
  0.2500000000000000  0.5000000000000000  0.2500000000000000  T T T
  0.2500000000000000  0.7500000000000000  0.0000000000000000  T T T
  0.5000000000000000  0.7500000000000000  0.2500000000000000  T T T
  0.7500000000000000  0.5000000000000000  0.2500000000000000  T T T
  0.7500000000000000  0.7500000000000000  0.0000000000000000  T T T
  0.0000000000000000  0.2500000000000000  0.7500000000000000  T T T
  0.2500000000000000  0.0000000000000000  0.7500000000000000  T T T
  0.2500000000000000  0.2500000000000000  0.5000000000000000  T T T
  0.5000000000000000  0.2500000000000000  0.7500000000000000  T T T
  0.7500000000000000  0.0000000000000000  0.7500000000000000  T T T
  0.7500000000000000  0.2500000000000000  0.5000000000000000  T T T
  0.0000000000000000  0.7500000000000000  0.7500000000000000  T T T
  0.2500000000000000  0.5000000000000000  0.7500000000000000  T T T
  0.2500000000000000  0.7500000000000000  0.5000000000000000  T T T
  0.5000000000000000  0.7500000000000000  0.7500000000000000  T T T
  0.7500000000000000  0.5000000000000000  0.7500000000000000  T T T
  0.7500000000000000  0.7500000000000000  0.5000000000000000  T T T
  0.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  T T T
  0.0000000000000000  0.5000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  T T T
  0.5000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  T T T
  0.5000000000000000  0.5000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  T T T
  0.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  0.5000000000000000  T T T
  0.0000000000000000  0.5000000000000000  0.5000000000000000  T T T
  0.5000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  0.5000000000000000  T T T
  0.5000000000000000  0.5000000000000000  0.5000000000000000  T T T
```

And this is the file I get: (T is for True and F for False, which I am trying to modify for certain atoms, don't mind the symbols Ni and Al, they are just for information)

```
0.000000 0.250000 0.250000 T T T Ni
0.250000 0.000000 0.250000 T T T Ni
0.250000 0.250000 0.000000 T T T Ni
0.500000 0.250000 0.250000 T T T Ni
0.750000 0.000000 0.250000 T T T Ni
0.750000 0.250000 0.000000 T T T Ni
0.000000 0.750000 0.250000 T T T Ni
0.250000 0.500000 0.250000 T T T Ni
0.250000 0.750000 0.000000 T T T Ni
0.500000 0.750000 0.250000 T T T Ni
0.750000 0.500000 0.250000 T T T Ni
0.750000 0.750000 0.000000 T T T Ni
0.000000 0.250000 0.750000 T T T Ni
0.250000 0.000000 0.750000 T T T Ni
0.250000 0.250000 0.500000 T T T Ni
0.500000 0.250000 0.750000 T T T Ni
0.750000 0.000000 0.750000 T T T Ni
0.750000 0.250000 0.500000 T T T Ni
0.000000 0.750000 0.750000 T T T Ni
0.250000 0.500000 0.750000 T T T Ni
0.250000 0.750000 0.500000 T T T Ni
0.500000 0.750000 0.750000 T T T Ni
0.750000 0.500000 0.750000 T T T Ni
0.750000 0.750000 0.500000 T T T Ni
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 T T T Al
0.000000 0.500000 0.000000 T T T Al
0.500000 0.000000 0.000000 T T T Al
0.500000 0.500000 0.000000 T T T Al
0.000000 0.000000 0.500000 T T T Al
0.000000 0.500000 0.500000 T T T Al
0.500000 0.000000 0.500000 T T T Al
0.500000 0.500000 0.500000 T T T Al
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's suspicious that you call the `write_file` function from INSIDE the for loop.  That causes the entire file to be written n times, and it won't be the same every time because you are modifying `struc` as you index through the loop.  Try moving that statement outside the loop and see what you get.

It's not clear if you're saying that the program behaves differently if you run it 'interactively' versus 'non-interactively', whatever that might mean.  You should clarify that.

Comment: I should clarify. I tried using the write_file function outside the loop, but still it doesn't help.  That's why I put it inside, but it gives the same output even though there are multiple times its being overwritten. By interactive, I mean you run the program interactively (python -i program), so you have the active console. In that case, I see the fields have been modified.  I hope this makes it clear, and I apologize I didn't elaborate it earlier.

Comment: if what you say is true, then the program isn't writing the final value of the data to the file.  Does the write_file function open and close the file properly?  How about printing to the console the value of `struct` as the last line of the program (you may need a loop to print the lines one at a time)?  If that's got the correct values, then the problem must be  somewhere in write_file.

Comment: Your are right. I can print the new fields separately outside the loop. Its just extra work to get rid of some punctuation marks and add a new header. I wish I could fix the issue with write_file as this inbuilt function does not have a close object. So I cannot close the file which is done for a general python file operation. Thanks for the help!